# how to increase the accuracy of Grabcut Algorithm using OpenCV?

Tags: android, algorithm, opencv

I am using the grabcut algorithm of OpenCV for the background subtraction of an image in android. Algorithms runs fine but the result it gives is not accurate.
E.g. My input image is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkChv.jpg]

Output image look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyp3O.jpg]

so How can we increase accuracy of Grabcut Algorithm?

P.S: Apology for not uploading example images due to low reputation :(

Comment: how to link :/ don't have any hosting for that..

Comment: Have you looked at [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html)?  It has sample images, sample code, and appears to address problems similar to the ones in your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been battling with the same problem for quite some time now. I have a few tips and tricks for this

1> Improve your seeds. Considering that GrabCut is basically a black box, to whom you give seeds and expect the segmented image as output, the seeds are all you can control and it becomes imperative to select good seeds. There are a number of things you can do in this regard if you have some expectation for the image you want to segment. For a few cases consider these:

a> Will your image have humans? Use a face detector to find the face and mark those pixels as Probable/definite foreground, as you deem fit. You could also use skin colour models within some region of interest to further refine your seeds

b> If you have some data on what kind of foreground you expect after segmentation, you can train colour models and use them as well to mark even more pixels

The list will go on. You need to creatively come up with different ways to adds more accurate seeds.

2> Post Processing: Try simple post processing techniques like the Opening and Closing operations to smoothen your fgmask. They will help you get rid of a lot of noise in the final output.

In general graphcut (and hence grabcut) tends to snap quickly to edges and hence if you have strong edges close to your foreground boundary, you can expect inaccuracies in the result.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I m new to the openCV so can you guide how to mark pixels of an image ?

Comment: Grabcut allows a seeds mask an input. Which means, for each pixel in the image, you can set one of the four values: GC_PR_FGD (probable foreground), GC_FGD(definite foreground), GC_BGD(background), GC_PR_BGD(probable background). So create a mask with same size as your image, and for each pixel set one of these values. If you need further help, I suggest you take a look at the documentation and some sample code, both of which are available on the openCV website.

Comment: hi @TheBlueNotebook , i facing some issue when making mask of same size please have a look hope you can help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180975/opencv-for-android-error-when-i-convert-color-image-to-grayscale]