# Opencv detection Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I will like to detect the hand in the following images. I have tried grabCut algorithm from opencv using the foreground and background extraction. However, there is some inaccuracy in the detection. Could someone help me with it, please. Thank You.

The code is as follow:

```
public static void DetectionAlg() {

        //convert from bitmap to mat
        Mat mat = new Mat(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap, mat);

        //covert to bgr
        Mat bgrMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, bgrMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);    

        Mat background = new Mat(bgrMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        Mat firstMask = new Mat();
        Mat bgModel = new Mat();
        Mat fgModel = new Mat();
        Mat mask;
        Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD));
        Mat dst = new Mat();
        //using a user define area
        Rect rect = new Rect(GlobalVar.tl, GlobalVar.br);

        Imgproc.grabCut(bgrMat, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 5, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
        Core.compare(firstMask, source, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ);

        Mat foreground = new Mat(bgrMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        bgrMat.copyTo(foreground, firstMask);

        Scalar color = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
        Imgproc.rectangle(bgrMat, GlobalVar.tl, GlobalVar.br, color);

        Mat tmp = new Mat();
        Imgproc.resize(background, tmp, bgrMat.size());
        background = tmp;
        mask = new Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        Mat vals = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0.0));
        background.copyTo(dst);
        background.setTo(vals, mask);

        Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask);

        firstMask.release();
        source.release();
        bgModel.release();
        fgModel.release();
        vals.release();

        Mat colorMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, colorMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colorMat.cols(), colorMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(colorMat, outputBitmap);

    }
```

Images are in the link:
[This is the input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zdok.jpg)
[This is another input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxyUi.jpg)
[This is the output using the above method, however, there are some other parts that does not belong to the hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O11FR.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to increase the accuracy of Grabcut Algorithm using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948606/how-to-increase-the-accuracy-of-grabcut-algorithm-using-opencv)

Comment: @RobAu, Thank you for your comment. As i am new to image processing, i might need some time to work on it. Do you have any other suggestions? It may not need to be grabcut.Thank you

Comment: Its is way to broad to explain all the different approaches that are possbile. Try to understand you input domain and read about image segmentation, background subtraction etc.